# How to remove the text "Published On:" in Post/Article pagee

Tags: wordpress

I’m using Avada layout to create my own custom layout for the single post blog (article/post) page.
I want the date meta to show, and its working as intended showing the date however before the date its writing “Published On:”.

Is there a way to remove completely or modify the text? (whether using the Avada options or through code)
Also I'm trying to figure out if this text "Published On:" is coming from the theme Avada or from Wordpress itself however I can't figure it out.

I actually tried to search all the website files for a text "Published On:" but it turned 0 results which made me baffled on where its coming from!

Image:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! it turned out not to be in the theme or wp files. but in the plugin that comes with Avada called Fusion Builder.

Comment: You saved me man, and not just "Published on" but many others are hidden behind Fusion Builder. Having Polyang, in settings I had to check ttf-Fusion-Builder. AND WOALA! Three hours haha :D

Answer (score 1):

in some themes there is an option where you can choose if this counter appear or not. For example the Salient theme options can do this.

If you wanna change the string, you can use Loco translate or edit the .PO langages files of Avada with the software "PoEdit" for example.

The other solution, to completly hide this text, is by using CSS.

Can you show us an example page please.

Comment: Hello Benfou, I actually looked at the .po file of Avada and there is no Published On there. as noted in the main question i looked inside all files (using good old eclipse which searches the text in every file) and didn't find it anywhere. sadly the website is still offline therefor i can not provide a link. The option available in Avada Meta Elements is to remove the published date or added it (and i need it to be added) however the problem is that once its added instead of showing only the date, it shows as well the text "Published On:" followed by the date.

Comment: And its all under one span ("Published On:" and the Date) so I can not remove it using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can remove labels by coosing "No".

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want change php theme files or translate .po, can replace strings "on the fly" with jquery, like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery('.related-posts > div > h3').html('Posts Relacionados');
/*]]>*/
});
</script>
```

Locate the parent class of string (xpath), and replace directly.

Comment: ...or sumply add a display:none on you css for this class